# Alarmmanager.setRepeating triggers Immediately

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Here is my code:

```
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, hourOfDay, minute,Calendar.SECOND);

Intent intent=new Intent(FaceActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(FaceActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Here hourOfDay is one hour past the current hour. minute may have the same value.

Now here cal.getTimeInMillis() is set for time that is one hour past the current time.
But when I run this code the broadcast receiver is called Immediately.
Can any one tell, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: show us your code where you setting the time in `cal`.I guess It `cal.getTimeInMillis()` is a past time.

Comment: Code gives not much information. :) Log `System.currentTimeMillis();` and `cal.getTimeInMillis()`. And then compare the results.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem Time After Setting(573): Calendar time is -62130303706613 Current time is 1350281798450  Calendar time is 2 minutes past current time

Comment: So...? API says `If the time occurs in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately...........`. So what is the problem?

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem Actually if the current time is 11:55 AM and I set the alarm for 11:58 AM, it should trigger at 11:58 AM only. But here it triggers twice, once at 11:55 AM and then at 11:58 AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found my mistake, I was getting the wrong values for `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Second`.

By using below code, it works perfectly fine.

```
cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourOfDay, minute,cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```